# Browsers differently interpret translate() and absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

When absolute positioned, div(id="inner") is larger then its parent element, and has `translateY()` applied. Each browser renders it differently.

On Chrome Canary and IE EDGE, div(id="inner") is larger than the window so they add a scrollbar. But Chrome and Firefox don't add the scroll bar.

Does anyone know why this is the case? Which browsers doing the right thing?

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#inner {
  position: absolute;
  height: calc(100vh + 100px);
  width: 70px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  transform: translateY(-100px);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="inner"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no scrollbar in Canary (on OSX, anyway), and would not expect to: the portion of the element that extends beyond the viewport is in the negative direction, which can't be scrolled to in any case.   Canary is a daily experimental build, so can be expected to have bugs; it's not where I'd look to find guaranteed correct behavior.

I haven't tested in Edge, but its rendering engine is [soon to be replaced by Chromium](https://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-building-chromium-powered-web-browser-windows-10).  Here, too, I wouldn't spend much concern about the behavior of a browser rendering engine that's effectively already EOL.

Scrollbar behavior isn't heavily specified in HTML, as far as I know; there's a lot of variation across platforms and browsers about how they are handled, so it's possible that neither behavior is specifically "incorrect" -- but in general I'd say it's safe to assume that if those two browsers differ from the rest of the web, trust the rest of the web.